# Show repeated value from MySQL DB once PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table in MySQL DB which stores Menu served by restaurant on each weekday and in time slots.

Table structure is as below:

```
  i_type      i_name    i_cost   i_day   i_start     i_end
  --------------------------------------------------------
  Breakfast   Prantha   20       Sunday   07:00      11:00
  Lunch       Special   80       Sunday   11:01      15:00
  Dinner      Special   100      Sunday   15:01      21:00
  Breakfast   Prantha1  50       Monday   07:00      11:00
  Lunch       Special1  70       Monday   11:01      15:00
  Dinner      Special1  130      Monday   15:01      21:00
```

I want to display menu as below:

```
<b>Sunday</b><br/>
    Breakfast<hr/>Prantha       20     Add<br/><br/>
    Lunch<br/><hr/>Special      80     Add<br/><br/>
    Dinner<br/><hr/>Special     100    Add<br/><hr/>
<b>Monday</b><br/>
   Breakfast<hr/>Prantha       20     Add<br/><br/>
   Lunch<br/><hr/>Special      80     Add<br/><br/>
   Dinner<br/><hr/>Special     100    Add<br/><hr/>
```

Currently i am handling it as below:

```
$sql = SELECT * FROM `tabl1` WHERE 1;      
$data = DB::instance()->prepare($sql)->execute()->fetchAll();
foreach($data as $row){
       //print values
 }

but this approach print Sunday and Monday multiple times.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just keep track of which day you've output, e.g. use a "state machine":

```
$previousday = null;
while($row = ... fetch from db... ) {
    if ($row['day'] != $previousday) {
       ... output day header
       $previousday = $row['day'];
    }
    ... output row data ...
}
```

Comment: this is perfect and served the purpose

Answer (score 1):

It will of course print three Sundays and three Mondays.

You could for example Select all different days first (SELECT DISTINCT (i_day) FROM menu), then for each day select all menus (SELECT * FROM menu WHERE i_day = ?)

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT (i_day) FROM menu";      
$data = DB::instance()->prepare($sql)->execute()->fetchAll();
foreach($data as $row){
  // Add all i_day's to an associative array $i_days
}
foreach($i_days as $day) {
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM menu WHERE i_day = $day";      
  $data = DB::instance()->prepare($sql)->execute()->fetchAll();
    foreach($data as $row){
      // Print values
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$stat = "SELECT * from TABLE_NAME";
$conn -> query ($stat);
foreach($conn -> query($stat) as $menu) {

echo $menu["i_day"];
echo $menu["i_type"];
echo $menu["i_name"];
echo $menu["i_cost"];

}
```

Format the above data basing on your need. I've just provided you the basic code.

Alternately,

```
$stat = "SELECT * from TABLE_NAME where i_day = 'DAY_GOES_HERE'";
$conn -> query ($stat);
foreach($conn -> query($stat) as $menu) {

echo $menu["i_type"];
echo $menu["i_name"];
echo $menu[i_cost];

}
```

Repeat it for each day.

Comment: because same has been described in above answer.